# Scraping information from a website with a 'Show More' button

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape information for dresses from this website: https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/

Obviously, I'm not only interested in the first 60 results, but all of them. When clicking on the 'Show More' button a couple of times, I arrive at this url: https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/#sz=60&start=300

I would have expected that using the following code, I get a full download of the page mentioned above, but for some reason, it will still only yield the first 60 results.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = "https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/#sz=60&start=300"

res = requests.get(url)
res.encoding = 'utf-8'
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
elements = soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class": "product product-tile"})
```

I can see that the issue lies within the request itself, since the `soup` variable does not contain the full html text I see when inspecting the page, but I can not figure out why that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below url which fetch you 331 elements.

> url : https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/?sz=331&start=0&format=ajax

```
import requests
import bs4

url="https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/?sz=331&start=0&format=ajax"
res = requests.get(url)
res.encoding = 'utf-8'
res.raise_for_status()
html = res.text

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
elements = soup.find_all("div", attrs = {"class": "product product-tile"})
print(len(elements))
```

Answer (score 1):

The link you show after having clicked to the "Show more" button uses **fragments** (notice the `#` sign).  This is not something sent to the server, but rather used by JavaScript in the front-end to load more items without reloading the full page.

However, you're lucky because if you look at the HTTP requests made in your browser console, you'll see that it does a request to `https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/?sz=60&start=60`. Those are query params (and seem to exactly match the fragments!), so this means the server will send the extra items.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked by sending multiple requests with different start values and consolidating the results!

Comment: As a side note, if you wish to code a reliable/maintainable scraper that is able to follow pages and so on, you should have a look at [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/). It [works with BeautifulSoup](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=beautifulsoup#can-i-use-scrapy-with-beautifulsoup), so you'll be able to keep your parsing logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case, the button "show more", load `*sz*` dress from the `*from*` th dress.

So when you do a http request with `#sz=60&start=300` attribute, the database will only fetch the dresses from index 300 to 360, that is why the request only contains 60 dresses.

There is another button on the page that indicate another url: *SHOW ALL*, this button give this url: `https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/?sz=120`

With only the `?sz=120` url parameter you could get a answer with `sz` number of dresses. But it seems there is a limit of how many dresses you can load at once.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP GET to https://www.libertylondon.com/uk/department/women/clothing/dresses/#sz=331&start=0 will return all items (331 is the current number of items and may be changed in the future)